# What is the proper way to pass data between child components?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a parent component called **SearchScreen.tsx**, within it there are 2 child components, **SearchBarView.tsx** and **SearchResultView.tsx**. The SearchBarView has a callback prop `onTextChanged(text)`, the text changed will be processed in the SearchScreen and pass the result to SearchResultView. The data passing is working as expected. Every time when new character is entered in SearchBarView, the above scenario will happen, the new **text change goes from  SearchBarView to SearchScreen, new search result generated and passed to SearchResultView. That means, when a user enters 'abcdefghij' in SearchBarView, this will happen 10 times because there are 10 characters in 'abcdefghij'.** Whenever this happens, all 3 components will rerender. In order to reduce the number of changes, I used a debounce while the search phrase is being entered, this will reduce the number of changes/rerenders. However, the rerender still causes a problem in SearchBarView. In SearchBarView, the search phrase is being tracked in a local state like this:

```
const [searchPhrase, setSearchPhrase] = useState('');
```

Every time when the parent component SearchScreen re-renders,  SearchBarView gets re-rendered, when SearchBarView get re-rendered that is caused by the parent component, it sets the searchPhrase back to empty string because **useState('')** initializes the searchPhrase to an empty string. So, the problem is in the end, the searchPhrase always ended up with empty string.

**Questions:**

Is it normal for all 3 components to re-render many many times while the user is entering the search phrase?

Are there ways to pass data from SearchBarView to SearchScreen and then to
SearchResultView without causing all 3 components to re-render?

How to address the issue that the searchPhrase always ended up in empty string?

It appears SearchBarView is being unmounted then mounted when SearchScreen re-re-renders. that caused the useState to take the initial empty value which makes the searchPhrase always ended up in empty string. Does re-render always unmount and mount again? How to prevent it to re-mounted?

**SearchScreen.tsx**

```
const SearchScreen: React.FC = () => {
  const [searchResult, setSearchResult] = useState<string[]>([]);

  const onSearchPhraseUpdate = (text: string) => {
    setSearchResult('some','search','result','strings');
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <SearchBarView
        onSearchPhraseUpdate={onSearchPhraseUpdate}
      />
      <SearchResultView
        results={searchResult}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );

};

export default SearchScreen;
```

**SearchBarView.tsx**

```
interface IProps {
  readonly onSearchPhraseUpdate: (text: string) => void;
}

const SearchBarView: React.FC<IProps> = (props) => {
  const { onBackButtonPress, onSearchPhraseUpdate } = props;
  const [searchPhrase, setSearchPhrase] = useState('');

  const _searchPhrase = _debounce((text: string)=>{
    setSearchPhrase(text);
    onSearchPhraseUpdate(text);
  }, 500);

  console.log("SearchBarView searchPhrase: ", searchPhrase);

  return (
    <SearchTextInput
        style={{flex: 1}}
        onChangeText={_searchPhrase}
        keyboardType='default'
    />
  );

};


export default SearchBarView;
```

**SearchResultView.tsx**

```
interface IProps {
  readonly results: string[];
}

const SearchResultView: React.FC<IProps> = (props) => {
  const { results } = props;

  return (
    <MyListView results={results}/>
  );

};

export default SearchResultView;
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is it normal for all 3 components to re-render many many times while the user is entering the search phrase?

Yes, since all 3 components gets an update:

1. `SearchBarView`: get direct input
2. `SearchScreen`: notified of the new text change by `SearchBarView`
3. `SearchResultView`: get new update `result` by `SearchScreen`

So all three components should re-render.

> Are there ways to pass data from SearchBarView to SearchScreen and then to SearchResultView without causing all 3 components to re-render?

No. Ff the update didn't happen, then the component will not be aware of the updates on the text the user entered.

> How to address the issue that the searchPhrase always ended up in empty string?

This is weird since `useState` takes the parameter value for one time only. The only case that `useState` could be the reason would be when the component gets unmounted then mounted again. but the problem may be from elsewhere.

It will be very useful If you can provide a working example on [codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/). but as a hint that may solve the issue: wrap every callback props with `useCallback` hook. that will make sure that no false updates will cause undesired re-render for `SearchResultView` and `SearchBarView`

Comment: yes, the SearchBarView is being unmounted then mounted when SearchScreen re-re-renders. that caused the useState to take the initial empty value which makes the  searchPhrase always ended up in empty string. does re-render always unmount and mount again? how to prevent it to re-mounted?

Comment: No, it is not normal to unmount and remount on on updates. the normal case for unmount is when the component removed from the DOM or in react when you stop rendering it. also if you send new `key` prop to the component, that will unmount and mount in again. You can check if the parent component `SearchScreen` also get unmount or not.